# Can I use a separate branch for one section of my site?

Tags: git, github

I have a standard Rails app that I manage via GitHub.

I have a static Jekyll site that I have the source code saved in `jekyll/support` in my app directory and then when I build the Jekyll site it is saved to `public/support`.

There are many updates / edits to these files and I want to try and separate them into branches.

My first thought was to add the above directories to my `.gitignore` files on my `master` and other main branches (i.e. `staging`).

I would then add all the other app folders (`app`, `bin`, etc) to the `.gitignore` file in my separate `support` branch.  This way I can have a clean version of just the support documents etc. to work on and then merge these into the other main branches when I am ready to push to production etc.

Can someone confirm that this is reasonable way to accomplish this?  If not suggest alternate methods etc.

Feel free to update this question if I have the wrong tags - not sure if one or both of the Git tags was appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would isolate your `jekyll/support` content in its own branch, while keeping your Rails app in its current branch, assuming they are two separate applications.

But if they are not, then you can make as many branch as you want, without having to ignore "all the other app folders (`app`, `bin`, etc)": as long as you don't modify those app folders, and only modify `jekyll/support`, you will be able to merge back those branches at any time.

Comment: To clarify I only want to update these files - my master and staging branches would have code that is / could be vastly different.  This is why I was thinking of the ignores.